# Time required for deceleration to occur

Tags: calculus, physics

Given the following, with the correct answer. What type of formula would be applied to this problem and how so?

An object falls freely in a straight line and experiences air resistance proportional to its​ speed; this means its acceleration is ​a(t)=−​kv(t), where k is a positive constant and v is the​ object's velocity. The speed of the object decreases from 1300 ft/s to 1200 ft/s over a distance of 1400 ft. Approximate the time required for this deceleration to occur.

I attempted to use the formula (1300^2 - 1200^2) / 1400^2 as suggested but it does not give the correct answer.

Correct Answer is: 1.1206

Comment: It sounds like it belongs on physics.se and we don't like to click through to find a problem, particularly a homework problem with no effort shown.

Comment: What does "divided by sfts/s" mean?

Comment: This is a problem related to exponential decay/growth @RossMillikan so it should belong here.

Comment: @Useless I fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The units of your calculation are sec$^{-2}$ so that formula cannot be right.  As a simple approximation, the average speed is about $1250$ ft/sec, so the deceleration time is $1400/1250=1.12$ seconds.  For more accuracy, you should solve $s=\frac 12at^2+v_0t$ with your data which will lower the average speed slightly and increase the time slightly.

Comment: Thank you for the response and information, so if I were to set up the given information with this formula $s=\frac 12at^2+v_0t$ would it look something like this? s = 1/2(1250)(1.12) + (1.12)

Comment: No  You can't plug in $1.12-$ that is what we are trying to solve for.  You also didn't square anything for the $\frac 12at^2$ term.  We know $s=1400$.  The velocity drops by $100$ so we have $at=-100$.  Plug those in and solve for $t$.  We get $1400=\frac 12 (-\frac {100}t)t^2+1300t$

Comment: I solved for t which came out to 28/25 which is the same as the first approximation, is there possibly a more accurate method to getting this answer? @RossMillikan